# SNOWFLAKE scripting: variable name not defined in procedure

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I tried to run:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE iterate_columns(table_name VARCHAR)
RETURNS VARCHAR
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
AS $$
    var sql_command = `SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = '${table_name}'`;
    var stmt = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: sql_command});
    var result_set = stmt.execute();
    var column_names = '';
    while (result_set.next()) {
        column_names += result_set.getColumnValue(1) + ', ';
    }
    return column_names.slice(0, -2);
$$;

CALL iterate_columns('MY_TABLE_NAME');
```

Error:
100132 (P0000): JavaScript execution error: Uncaught ReferenceError: table_name is not defined in ITERATE_COLUMNS at ' var sql_command = `SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = ${table_name}`;' position 95
stackstrace:
ITERATE_COLUMNS line: 2

And this runs fine:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'MY_TABLE_NAME';
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [100132 (P0000): JavaScript execution error: Uncaught ReferenceError:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60046332/100132-p0000-javascript-execution-error-uncaught-referenceerror)

Comment: variable names are case insensitive in SQL, but sensitive in JavaScript, AND SQL default to upper case, so in the JS you need to use `TABLE_NAME`

Answer (score 1):

Moving the helpful comments to an answer for closure:

- Use upper caps:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE iterate_columns(TABLE_NAME VARCHAR)
RETURNS VARCHAR
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
AS $$
    var sql_command = `SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = '${TABLE_NAME}'`;
    var stmt = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: sql_command});
    var result_set = stmt.execute();
    var column_names = '';
    while (result_set.next()) {
        column_names += result_set.getColumnValue(1) + ', ';
    }
    return column_names.slice(0, -2);
$$;

CALL iterate_columns('MY_TABLE_NAME');
```

Or define in quoted lower caps:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE iterate_columns("table_name" VARCHAR)
```